# Are there any serverless distributed filesystems?

Tags: linux, cluster, distributed-filesystems

Similar to [Is there a Distributed SAN/Storage System out there?](https://serverfault.com/questions/130209/is-there-a-distributed-san-storage-system-out-there) or [Distributed redundant storage solution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/211825/distributed-redundant-storage-solution), except with a couple key differences (and two years newer).

Context: I have a small Rocks cluster (a few dozen machines of varying capabilities), and would like to have all of my nodes pool their excess storage space to allow for a distributed filesystem.  I maybe can spare a machine that would act as a server for it, but would prefer not to.

Unlike the above, all of these machines share user lists, and no user can gain root--security and encryption concerns are nearly negligible. (FS mounted by root; contains one directory per user with their perms)

I feel like it should be pretty easy to do, I just can't find any solutions that aren't WAY more complicated than what I'm looking for.

EDIT: My motivation is that every now and then a big IO load hits, taking down the NFS.  I am well aware that "go buy a nice SAN with a bunch of SSDs" is a quite nice solution; it's just not available at the moment--I'd like to know what I can do with software and the hardware I have.

Comment: If you haven't, take a look at GlusterFS

Comment: I read over its description before, but hadn't previously considered making all machines simultaneously clients and servers... does that even work? (without insane overhead)

Comment: I don't think you have to use clients as servers, but it is a versatile file virtualization platform.

Comment: It doesn't appear designed for that-- I was wondering if I could choose to do so (so I don't have to dedicate any servers).  I believe the answer might be yes.

Comment: What about Dat and IPFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very good answer, but I'd like to make the question closed.

uSlackr's suggestion of GlustreFS seems to the best option.  There are a number of examples of it being used on clusters, and its elastic hash metadata model means that there is no centralized metadata server.

There is nothing that says a single machine cannot run both client and server.

That said, it fulfills the requirements as outlined.